# How in handsontable scroll to row?

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

Set the range of visible lines or scroll to the desired table row during initialization.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#id').handsontable('selectCell', row1, col1, row2, col2, scrollToSelection = true)
$('#id').handsontable('deselectCell');
```

Comment: I wanted to do this same thing, but the problem I have with a similar approach because it blurs the currently focused element. In my case I save document.activeElement before selectCell and then call focus on that saved element after deselectCell.